# Export .mov 1080i60 (59.94i) 29.97 fps Adobe Premiere

Tags: premiere, quicktime, export

I've done this before in an older version of adobe premiere but I can't seem to remember how to get the export settings correct.

I need to export in:
1080i at 29.97fps with resolution 1920x1080 as a .mov file

I found these settings under H.264 and HD1080i 29.97 but it forces a .mp4 file. Under quicktime I don't seem to have the 1080i presets. Am I missing the settings or is there something I can do to make this work?

Here is a chart for the standards I'm trying to follow:
[image: Specs Chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download [Quicktime](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL837?locale=en_US) to enable missing codecs
2. In export settings select "Quicktime" for format
3. Ignore preset, scroll down to video codec and select H.264